# Extract public key from cer file to use in nusoap

Tags: php, web-services, certificate, nusoap

Can someone tell me how can I extract a public keu in .pem format from a .cer file ?
I'm trying to configure webservice over https with nusoap.

Tks,
ED

Answer (score 4):

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in <certificate> -noout -pubkey
```

Should print out the public key.

Answer (score 2):

Any time I need to convert certificate formats I like to hop on my Linux shell and use the openssl CLI.

Take a look at [this page](http://shib.kuleuven.be/docs/ssl_commands.shtml) for common openssl commands.  You will be most interested in the one titled "Convert DER (.crt .cer .der) to PEM".